# How to stop HostedService programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I'm building a dotnet core HostedService app. I need to stop application after some period of time.

How can I stop it?

I've tried to add to StartAsync method

```
await Task.Delay(5000);
Environment.Exit(0);
```

Main:

```
static Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<EventsService>();
        })
        .UseLogging();

    return hostBuilder.RunConsoleAsync();
}
```

it doesn't work. How can I correctly stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`RunConsoleAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostinghostbuilderextensions.runconsoleasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0) accepts a `CancellationToken`. You can create a `CancellationTokenSource` that signals cancellation after a given number of milliseconds:

```
var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(5000);

return hostBuilder.RunConsoleAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

With this, the application shuts down after *roughly* five seconds.